# Xamarin Forms método Clicked no responde

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en un formulario muy simple en **Xamarin**, de momento solo quiero validar campos vacíos y obtener su valor, el problema esta en que a veces  no consigo ejecutar el método que quiero con un click, no hay ningún tipo de error, pero no jala muy bien. La clase que quiero instancear la llamo desde un **toolbar_item**, cuando llamo a la clase como la vista principal, corre mucho mejor, pero según yo no debería ser el caso.

Con cada click al botón obtengo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Toolbar

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace OwService
{
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
  public MainPage()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
            
        }

       


        private void ToolbarItem_Login(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //navigation

            Navigation.PushAsync(new PageAuth());
        }

    }
}
```

Controlador y vista

```js
namespace OwService {
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class PageAuth: ContentPage {
    public PageAuth() {

      InitializeComponent();

      //btnAuth.Clicked += Auth_Clicked;
    }



    private async void Auth_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      await Try_Mr();



    }

    private async Task Try_Mr() {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userTxt.Text)) {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Por favor ingrese su nombre de usuario", "ok");
        userTxt.Focus();
        return;

      }
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(passTxt.Text)) {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Por favor ingrese una contraseña", "ok");
        passTxt.Focus();
        return;
      }

      await DisplayAlert("Alert", "" + passTxt.Text + " " + userTxt.Text, "ok");
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="OwService.PageAuth">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="20,120,20,180">

      <StackLayout Margin="0,40,0,0">
        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="waitActIndicator" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Bienvenido a OwService!" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
      <Label Text="Ingresa tus datos para continuar " HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
      <Entry x:Name="userTxt" />
      <Entry x:Name="passTxt" IsPassword="True" />
      <Button x:Name="btnAuth" Clicked="Auth_Clicked" />

    </StackLayout>


  </ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage>
```

Comment: Buenas, lo primero dices que eso ocurre "a veces"? Lo que muestras como un error no son errores, es solo que una tarea ha terminado. Que significa que "no jala muy bien"? ¿Va lento, da errores, no hace algo que quieres?

Comment: @Mulflar pues si mi amigo, "no jala" no "funciona" al 100%, se retrasaba un poco en leer los entrys y así, resolví mi problema poniendo todo enn un solo **stack layout** y reiniciando  **vs**

Comment: Te pido disculpas si te he ofendido. No pretendia que mi comentario fuera irrespetuoso de alguna manera, "no jala" o "no funciona" para el caso es lo mismo, lo que queria era que contaras el problema exacto. Si te iba lento es un problema de rendimiento, si le das al click y no hace nada es otra cosa. etc... etc...

Comment: @Mulflar "sin pedos" ('sin pedos' = expresión que puede denotar diversos significados dependientes del contexto, en el actual 'sin problemas') man ;) gracias por tu tiempo